# why my first column will become column 0 in a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

my input file with 8 columns. I have 38 file want to merge together.
input file: AAA.out

```
             pos     gpos         p1        ihh1        p2        ihh2  xpehh
 9.1022217  1022217 1.02222e+06 0.138333    901220  0.0738636   572286  0.454111  

 9.1024910  1024910 1.02491e+06 0.138333    900853  0.0738636   572286  0.453703  

 9.1041353  1041353 1.04135e+06 0.246667    852186  0.0738636   573584  0.3959  

 9.1070162  1070162 1.07016e+06 0.113333    870718  0   583622  0.400065
```

The BBB.out

```
             pos      gpos          p1       ihh1       p2      ihh2    xpehh
  8.1135641 1135641 1.13564e+06 0.368333    639953  0.352273    512804  0.2215  
  8.1152035 1152035 1.15204e+06 0.00333333  651548  0   540213  0.187389
  8.1158202 1158202 1.1582e+06  0.358333    646188  0   540213  0.179129
  8.1178735 1178735 1.17874e+06 0.01    654438  0.409091    486335  0.29688
  8.1193344 1193344 1.19334e+06 0   651573  0   497049  0.270699
  8.1230464 1230464 1.23046e+06 0.373333    631599  0.505682    482294  0.269701
```

I try to merge them by

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "*.*.out", full.names = TRUE, recursive = FALSE)  
#make a list of all out.files
uridata <- data.frame()
#go through each file, one by one, and add it to the 'uridata' df,   above  
big_list_of_data_frames <- lapply(files, read.table, skip = FALSE,header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)  
big_data_frame <- do.call(rbind,big_list_of_data_frames)
new_fram <- big_data_frame [,c(1,7)]  

the dput:  
structure(list(pos = c(1022217L, 1024910L, 1041353L, 1070162L, 
1089884L), gpos = c(1022220, 1024910, 1041350, 1070160, 1089880
), p1 = c(0.138333, 0.138333, 0.246667, 0.113333, 0.113333), 
    ihh1 = c(901220L, 900853L, 852186L, 870718L, 870014L), p2 =      c(0.0738636, 
0.0738636, 0.0738636, 0, 0), ihh2 = c(572286L, 572286L, 573584L, 
583622L, 583435L), xpehh = c(0.454111, 0.453703, 0.3959, 
0.400065, 0.399577)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("9.1022217", 
"9.1024910", "9.1041353", "9.1070162", "9.1089884"))
```

I hope my output file in csv

```
    ID             XPEHH  
    9.1022217     0.454111  
    9.1024910     0.453703
    9.1041353     0.3959 
    .
    .
    .
    8.1135641     0.2215
```

However, I don't know why the first column in input file will become a column 0 in the big_data_fram?

Can you give a any suggestions?

Comment: How many files do you have? do they have the same structure, Can you share sample data?

Comment: I have 38 out.files and they all have same structure

Comment: Can you read one file and dump sample data with `dput`

Comment: Please update the question with `dput` output

Comment: it looks like I have to convert the rownames to a proper column

Comment: There is no "column zero" in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing very well in your approach to merging the files. Your issue lies in how you read the files with `read.table`, as `read.table` assumes that if the first column name is missing, the first column is the rownames. See here:

```
> read.table(text=BBB, header=TRUE)
              pos    gpos         p1   ihh1       p2   ihh2    xpehh
8.1135641 1135641 1135640 0.36833300 639953 0.352273 512804 0.221500
8.1152035 1152035 1152040 0.00333333 651548 0.000000 540213 0.187389
8.1158202 1158202 1158200 0.35833300 646188 0.000000 540213 0.179129
8.1178735 1178735 1178740 0.01000000 654438 0.409091 486335 0.296880
8.1193344 1193344 1193340 0.00000000 651573 0.000000 497049 0.270699
8.1230464 1230464 1230460 0.37333300 631599 0.505682 482294 0.269701
> rownames(read.table(text=BBB, header=TRUE))
[1] "8.1135641" "8.1152035" "8.1158202" "8.1178735" "8.1193344" "8.1230464"
```

Ahh, look at `?read.table` about the `row.names` argument. TLDR; disable it by setting it to NULL.

```
> read.table(text=BBB, row.names = NULL, header=TRUE)
  row.names     pos    gpos         p1   ihh1       p2   ihh2    xpehh
1 8.1135641 1135641 1135640 0.36833300 639953 0.352273 512804 0.221500
2 8.1152035 1152035 1152040 0.00333333 651548 0.000000 540213 0.187389
3 8.1158202 1158202 1158200 0.35833300 646188 0.000000 540213 0.179129
4 8.1178735 1178735 1178740 0.01000000 654438 0.409091 486335 0.296880
5 8.1193344 1193344 1193340 0.00000000 651573 0.000000 497049 0.270699
6 8.1230464 1230464 1230460 0.37333300 631599 0.505682 482294 0.269701
> rownames(read.table(text=BBB, row.names = NULL, header=TRUE))
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6"
```

You can see here, that the first column is conveniently named "row.names". If the column names are fixed beforehand, you could simply provide a vector of names with the `col.names` argument to specify the names for the first column.

For these examples, I have read the contents of a file from a string in variable `BBB` using the `text` argument; you will have to substitute this with the file argument and the file name.